# Minimal driver installation for Wacom tablet?

Tags: driver, kernel-extensions, digitizer, wacom

I have a CTH-680 digitizer. Wacom all-in-one driver seems to install unnecessary stuff to the system. What can be removed? Or how to do a minimal installation?

```
├── Applications
│   └── Wacom Tablet.localized
│       ├── Wacom Desktop Center.app
│       ├── Wacom Display Settings.app
│       ├── Wacom Tablet Utility.app
│       └── aft.tar
└── Library
    ├── Application Support
    │   └── Tablet
    │       ├── TabletDriver.app
    │       ├── UserHelp
    │       ├── WacomTabletDriver.app
    │       └── WacomTouchDriver.app
    ├── Extensions
    │   ├── FTDIKext.kext
    │   └── SiLabsUSBDriver64.kext
    ├── Frameworks
    │   └── WacomMultiTouch.framework
    ├── Internet Plug-Ins
    ├── LaunchAgents
    │   ├── com.wacom.DataStoreMgr.plist
    │   ├── com.wacom.IOManager.plist
    │   └── com.wacom.wacomtablet.plist
    ├── LaunchDaemons
    │   ├── com.wacom.UpdateHelper.plist
    │   └── com.wacom.displayhelper.plist
    ├── PreferencePanes
    │   └── WacomTablet.prefpane
    ├── Preferences
    │   └── Tablet
    │       └── Wacom App Specific Settings
    └── PrivilegedHelperTools
        ├── com.wacom.DataStoreMgr.app
        ├── com.wacom.IOManager.app
        └── com.wacom.UpdateHelper.app
```

Comment: To what end? What do you consider 'unnecessary'?